# toString method

Tags: java

I want to add a `toString` method in the `Item` class that returns the title of the item in there.

I have need make sure that the toString method in the `DVD` class calls the `toString` method in `Item` so that it can return a string that contains both the title and the director.

`Item` is the superclass and `DVD` is the subclass.

```
  public class Item
   {
  private String title;
  private int playingTime;
  private boolean gotIt;
  private String comment;

public Item(String theTitle, int time)
{
    title = theTitle;
    playingTime = time;
    gotIt = false;
    comment = "<no comment>";
}

// Getters and setters omitted

public void print()
{
    System.out.print(title + " (" + playingTime + " mins)");
    if(gotIt) {
        System.out.println("*");
    } else {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("    " + comment);
}
```

}

```
 public class DVD extends Item 
 {
 private String director;

public DVD(String theTitle, String theDirector, int time)
{
    super(theTitle, time);
    director = theDirector;
}

// Getters and setters omitted

public void print()
{
    System.out.println("    director: " + director);
}
```

}

Comment: I've rephrased the question to make it more readable please feel free to rollback it if that's not what you meant.

Comment: If this is homework please tag it as such

Answer (score 6):

Item `toString`:

```
public String toString()
{
  return title;
}
```

DVD `toString`:

```
public String toString()
{
  return super.toString() + " director: " + director;
}
```

Also, I don't know what you're trying to do with this but I would put those `print()` methods in these classes.

You will be better of returning the string representation and printing it somewhere else (with this you can test this class without mocking `System.out`)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

A `toString` method is already defined in each Java class (it inherits the `toString` of `Object`). But it will return a practically meaningless value (AFAIR, the internal address/id of the instance within the JDK - I might be wrong).

What you need to do is to override that method and make it return a `String` that is the title of the `Item`. For the DVD class, you have to override `toString` and make it a string made up of the concatenation of the title and director.

For the `Item` class, your method should look something like this:

```
public String toString(){
   return this.title;
}
```

You should be able to use the same idea to implement `toString` for DVD.

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez: I did not want to just post code and hand in the solution. This looks too much like a homework assignment. I have posted how its done and provided example code. The OP can use that to code his solution. But if I just post code, most homework questioners will just use it and not learn anything. This point is moot however, since your answer has already given away code.

Comment: @MAK the question is not tagged as homework. This is a Q & A site, if the PO wants a tutorial he sure will find it elsewhere

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez: Do you think everyone who is too lazy to learn/do his own homework tags his own question as "homework"? This is a Q & A site, not a "outsource your homework" site. I'm not saying its not ok to ask for help/hints about homework, but I do not support encouraging people to just come here and their work done for them. It exploits the goodwill and time of people who could be helping people learn or get around real problems.

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez: Also, please see the [discussion about this in meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812).

Comment: @MAK thanks for pointing that out. If the question is indeed homework then your answer is the right one and deserves the upvotes (and being marked as accepted too). Sadly all I can do is give you +1