# toString method

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [toString method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5523447/tostring-method)

I have been asked to change the print method into a toString method that displays the exact same information when called. I'm not sure how i can put the if statements of the print method into the tostring function. Here is the original class we have been given. any help is appreciated!

```
 public class Item
 {
private String title;
private int playingTime;
private boolean gotIt;
private String comment;

/**
 * Initialise the fields of the item.
 * @param theTitle The title of this item.
 * @param time The running time of this item.
 */
public Item(String theTitle, int time)
{
    title = theTitle;
    playingTime = time;
    gotIt = false;
    comment = "<no comment>";
}

/**
 * Enter a comment for this item.
 * @param comment The comment to be entered.
 */
public void setComment(String comment)
{
    this.comment = comment;
}

/**
 * @return The comment for this item.
 */
public String getComment()
{
    return comment;
}

/**
 * Set the flag indicating whether we own this item.
 * @param ownIt true if we own the item, false otherwise.
 */
public void setOwn(boolean ownIt)
{
    gotIt = ownIt;
}

/**
 * @return Information whether we own a copy of this item.
 */
public boolean getOwn()
{
    return gotIt;
}




    /**
 * Print details of this item to the text terminal.
 */
public void print()
{
    System.out.print(title + " (" + playingTime + " mins)");
    if(gotIt) {
        System.out.println("*");
    } else {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("    " + comment);
}
```

}

Comment: -1 vote to mark for others to close this unnecessary thread.

Comment: After asking the same question 45 min ago, you ignore the good answers you got and asked again?

Comment: i was just unsure of how to put the if statement into the tostring. Jeez. don't be so harsh!

Comment: Don't make us duplicate effort done before -- especially if you ignore the previous advice! Also what do you expect we're going to say if you choose to ignore the forum rules about multiposting questions?

Answer (score 2):

The `toString()` method is simply a method *like any other*. It just has to return a String.

To convert your existing `print()` method:

1. rename it to `toString()`
2. declare it to return a `String`
3. build the string in the method using a `StringBuilder` and call `toString()` on that to get your return value

Comment: The problem is how do i incorporate the if statements into the return string though?

Comment: You incorporate your 'if' statements into the construction of the String via your StringBuilder. e.g. if (whatever) { buffer.append("*"); }

Answer (score 2):

This is not the most efficient or best way to do it, but it is easy to understand. It resembles the `print()` function quite a lot. The easier way to do it is the toString method below.

```
public void print()
{
    System.out.print(title + " (" + playingTime + " mins)");
    if(gotIt) {
        System.out.println("*");
    } else {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("    " + comment);
}
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String r = title + " (" + playingTime + " mins)";
    if(gotIt) {
        r = r + "*\n";
    } else {
        r = r + "\n";
    }
    r = r + "    " + comment;
    return r;
}
public void print2()
{
    System.out.println( this.toString() );
}
```